# VB.NET CHange default tooltip text upon button MouseHover

Tags: vb.net, tooltip

I am trying to add a custom tooltip with a custom text and I noticed that I already have a default tooltip that says the text of the button the mouse hovers over and when I add my own - now there are two tooltips (the default one and my custom one). So my question is how do I change the text of that default tooltip?

The code I wrote for my custom tooltip is

```
    Sub DynamicButton_Photos_MouseHover(ByVal sender As Button, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Form1.ToolTip.SetToolTip(sender, "My custom text")

    End Sub
```

Comment: We don't know what do you have in `Form1`. We don't know about your custom ToolTip. Please, make a good case.

Comment: There's literally nothing more... there's just a default tooltip appearing on every button I make and I need to find how to change exactly that tooltip and not create a new one because it results in two tooltips at the same time

Comment: Two ToolTip pop up could mean that you have two+ ToolTip components. Make sure that you don't create a new ToolTip component when you create new button. You need just one in a Form.

Comment: I don't have any tooltip components at all. That's the fun part :D this seems to be a default behaviour of every button

Comment: ah, and what's this: `Form1.ToolTip.SetToolTip(sender, "My custom text")`? Please edit your question and post the relevant code to help us understand the problem.

Comment: I've just explained it twice and what you're asking is ``The code I wrote for my custom tooltip is``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252044/discussion-between-eduards-and-dr-null).

Answer (score 1):

You must already have a tooltip created on the page, static in the form1.design file

```
 Me.ToolTip1 = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(Me.components)
```

or dynamic via a global declaration

```
Dim toolTip1 As New ToolTip
```

If you delete them to keep only one (Named Tooltip to follow your code example) you will no longer have overlapping of text.

Comment: And that's the thing that my entire solution doesn't have anything "ToolTip" related in it when I try to ctrl + F for it in the entire solution

Answer (score 0):

Set the default tooltip text for the button:

```
button1.ToolTipText = "My custom text"
```